# UI button click with no effect [Appium(1.4.16) Android(5.1)]

Tags: android, android-layout, appium, python-appium

It's my first question here, so don't blame me if I ask something stupid. (:

For my automation project in python, I need to implement adding Google account to Android device(genymotion device: Google Nexus 5 w/ 5.1 Android) via Settings -> Accounts -> Add new Account

However, after entering email of a test user with

```
email_field = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=LoginVariables.EMAIL_FIELD)
email_field.send_keys(GlobalVariables.USERNAME)
```

and pressing on a "NEXT" button

```
next_button = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=LoginVariables.NEXT_BUTTON)
next_button.click()
```

nothing happens, and I'm not moved to a "password page".
I see that button press animation on a clicked button is working, but after that, I'm stuck on an "email page".

That is the example of a page i get, and a button i need to press:
[Example login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE4Ds.png)

AFAIK, its context is a "NATIVE_APP", so there's no need to switch.

Is there any ways to "win" that native button?

P.S. Sending driver.press_keycode(66) works fine for login and password pages, where we have input, but not for the last ("accept page").
P.S.S. I was also trying to use long_press, tap and touch actions, but none of them helped to solve the issue.((

Comment: be it a native element of a webview element, if your `next_button` is displayed and clicked it should perform the action desired. Are you sure "I see that button press animation on a clicked button is working, but after that, I'm stuck on an "email page"" is not because of some sync ongoing in background or device not responding at that moment??

Comment: @nullpointer Hi. I'm pretty sure that there's no sync in background, and device is still working as usual. So, the main problem is that when i just do LMB on a "Next" button" in Genymotion, progress bar appears, and then sends me to a next screen. This doesn't happen when using .click() or .tap(). next_button web driver element is actually visible and clickable, but it looks like it doesn't perform needed action when pressing using appium. Any ideas what type of touch should i try?